# Python Reading file error with array

Tags: python, arrays, file

My File:

```
Offices 10
MedicalOffice 15
PostOffice 30
Mall 200
```

How do I make the python to read only the second column.
Like get:

```
10
15
30
200
```

I have tried possibly ways to make it only read, 10, 15, 30, etc... Instead of the names. I tried this without the names, it works fine. But I need to include the names in the textfile. Any help? Thanks

```
def something(file1):
    with file1 as f:
        nums = [int(line) for line in f]
        print("Read from File: ", nums)


textFileName = input("Enter the filename: ")
file1 = open(textFileName)
something(file1)
```

Thank you.

Comment: That's the second _column_. The second _row_ is `MedicalOffice 15`.

Comment: @abarnert good catch there. My typo. Thanks for heads up!

Comment: Yeah, I figured it was just a typo, but better to fix it than to confuse future readers…

Comment: Meanwhile, you probably don't want to do the `open` at the top level, and the `with` inside the function. That does basically work, as long as you only ever call `something` in this one case, but it's strange. Normally you want the `open` directly in the `with` statement. Either `with open(textFileName) as file1: something(file1)` and then `something` doesn't have a `with`, or just `something(textFileName)` and inside `something` it opens the file in a `with`. (This is very hard to explain in a comment; hopefully you get the idea?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't only read the second column.

But you can read both columns, ignore the first column, and only *use* the second.

For example:

```
def something(file1):
    with file1 as f:
        lines = (line.partition(' ') for line in f)
        nums = [int(line[-1]) for line in lines)
        print("Read from File: ", nums)
```

I did this in two steps, just to make it easier to see the part that's new (the `partition`) vs. the part you already had (the `int`). You can cram it all together into a single listcomp if you prefer:

```
        nums = [int(line.partition(' ')[-1]) for line in f]
```

Anyway, `partition` splits each line at the first space, so you get, e.g., `('Offices', ' ', '10')`. The `[-1]` takes the last part, the `'10'`. And then there's the `int`, which you already know about.

Answer (score 3):

To read the second column, split the lines and take the second field:

```
[x.split()[1] for x in open(textFileName,"r")]
```

If you want numbers, just call int:

```
[int(x.split()[1]) for x in open(textFileName,"r")]
```

Comment: Why did you add the `.readlines()` here? It wasn't in the original question, and all it does is make the program use more memory and more CPU (and more typing) for no benefit.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @Nirk's answer, but with improved file handling:

```
with open('/path/to/file.txt', 'r') as f:
    nums = [x.strip().split()[-1] for x in f]
```